# Group by in SQL Server giving wrong count

Tags: sql

I have a query which works, goes like this:

```
Select 
   count(InsuranceOrderLine.AntallPotensiale) as potensiale,
   COUNT(InsuranceOrderLine.AntallSolgt) as Solgt, 
   InsuranceProduct.Name,     
   InsuranceProductCategory.Name as Kategori
From 
   InsuranceOrderLine, InsuranceProduct, InsuranceProductCategory
where 
   InsuranceOrderLine.FKInsuranceProductId = InsuranceProduct.InsuranceProductID 
   and InsuranceProduct.FKInsuranceProductCategory = InsuranceProductCategory.InsuranceProductCategoryID
Group by 
   InsuranceProduct.name, InsuranceProductCategory.Name
```

This query over returns what I need, but when I try to add more table (`InsuranceOrder`) to be able to get the `regardingUser` column, then all the count values are way high.

```
Select 
    count(InsuranceOrderLine.AntallPotensiale) as Potensiale,
    COUNT(InsuranceOrderLine.AntallSolgt) as Solgt, 
    InsuranceProduct.Name, 
    InsuranceProductCategory.Name as Kategori, 
    RegardingUser
From 
    InsuranceOrderLine, InsuranceProduct, InsuranceProductCategory, InsuranceSalesLead
where 
    InsuranceOrderLine.FKInsuranceProductId = InsuranceProduct.InsuranceProductID 
    and InsuranceProduct.FKInsuranceProductCategory = InsuranceProductCategory.InsuranceProductCategoryID       
Group by 
    InsuranceProduct.name, InsuranceProductCategory.Name,RegardingUser
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You added `InsuranceSalesLead` table but you didn't specify the way it's related to other tables that's why the counts are multiplied and so high.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding one more table to your `FROM` statement, but you don't specify any `JOIN` condition for that table - so your previous result set will do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` (cartesian product) with your new table! Of course you'll get duplication of data....

That's one of the reasons that I'm recommending never to use that old, legacy style `JOIN` - do not simply list a comma-separated bunch of tables in your `FROM` statement.

**Always** use the new **ANSI standard JOIN** syntax with `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and so on:

```
SELECT
    count(iol.AntallPotensiale) as Potensiale,
    COUNT(iol.AntallSolgt) as Solgt, 
    ip.Name, 
    ipc.Name as Kategori, 
    isl.RegardingUser
FROM
    dbo.InsuranceOrderLine iol
INNER JOIN
    dbo.InsuranceProduct ip ON iol.FKInsuranceProductId = ip.InsuranceProductID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.InsuranceProductCategory ipc ON ip.FKInsuranceProductCategory = ipc.InsuranceProductCategoryID       

INNER JOIN 
    dbo.InsuranceSalesLead isl ON ???????? -- JOIN condition missing here !!
```

When you do this, you first of all see right away that you're missing a `JOIN` condition here - how is this new table `InsuranceSalesLead` linked to any of the other tables already used in this SQL statement??

And secondly, your intent is much clearer, since the `JOIN` conditions linking the tables are where they belong - right with the `JOIN` - and don't clutter up your `WHERE` clauses ...

Comment: Thank you very much, I added a GROUP BY at the end. You still have to do this using the INNER JOIN, right? I will absolutely start learning how do use Joins instead of the "old ways"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you added the table join which slightly multiplies count of rows - make sure, that you properly joining the table. And be careful with aggregate functions over several joined tables - joins very often lead to duplicates